# Why does the script work line by line, but does not work as a whole?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get

If I run this script all by Chrome Console - I get error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'playlist' of undefined

```js
var owner = "yamusic-trending"
var kind = "1000"
var url = `https://music.yandex.ru/handlers/playlist.jsx?owner=${owner}&kinds=${kind}&light=false`

json = $.getJSON(url)
var tracks = json.responseJSON["playlist"]['tracks']
```

By if line by line

```
json = $.getJSON(url)
```

And then

```
var tracks = json.responseJSON["playlist"]['tracks']
```

Error is not. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is aynchronous call and you need to wait until it get completed. If any of the operation dependes on the result return by this call then it should be handled in callback function.

see below code

**ES5**

```js
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
       var tracks = data.responseJSON["playlist"]['tracks']
    });
```

**ES6**

```js
$.getJSON(url, json => {
  var tracks = json.responseJSON["playlist"]['tracks']
});
```

**[getJSON API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)**

Comment: Can I specify an external function instead of this way `..function(data){..}`?

Answer (score 5):

As `$.getJSON` is an async `function`, you must handle it once it's done, here is an example using a callback:

```
$.getJSON(url, json => {
  var tracks = json.responseJSON["playlist"]['tracks']
  // do something with tracks here...
})
```

Read more about `$.getJSON` [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) , and read more about how asynchronous javascript works [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff)

Comment: i think you need to declare var out of the function so that you have broad scope...

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS ofcourse, but op didn't mention that `tracks` has to be global scoped.